# syntax error in inheriting python unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, python-unittest

So I'm writing unit test cases in python for the first time. Here's what I've got so far

```
 import unittest
 from . BinarySearchTree import BinarySearchTree

 def Test_bst(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        bst = BinrySearchTree()
        bst.put(21, "a")
        bst.put(18, "b")
        bst.put(10, "c")
        bst.put(40, "d")
        bst.put(8, "e")
        bst.put(11, "f")

    def test_get(self):
        self.assertEqual("f", bst.get(11))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

main()
```

Obviously I'm testing a binary search tree in the same directory. The issue I'm having is when I run this file I get an error that looks like

```
  File "Test_bst.py", line 4
    def Test_bst(unittest.TestCase):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm just pretty confused because I've been reading all of the documentation and I'm pretty sure it's all correct and I can't find any similar issues. Thanks y'all

Comment: A function cannot inherit anything.  Perhaps that was supposed to be a `class`, not a `def`?

Comment: have a look at my unittest demo https://www.github.com/IT-Support-L2/Unit_Test_Demo/tree/master/PythonUnitTest.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
class Test_bst(unittest.TestCase):
```

instead of

```
def Test_bst(unittest.TestCase):
```

I'd recommend reading the [unittest documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) on how to use the library, which also includes a basic example for creating test cases by inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`.